# How to make a Python Glob module work Cross-Platform (os.path issues)?

Tags: python, path, cross-platform

so I have some files layed out like this: './Example 3/ex3A.txt'

This script basically needs to list the content of a random text file that match the criteria I pass to it (in this case, a number).  The actual script does much more things to it, but this is the section I'm having trouble with.

This works perfectly on my linux machine, but I can't figure out how to do this on my coworker's windows pc.  I've tried various iterations of os.join.path and the like, but I can't seem to get this to work cross platform.

Here is the stock version of the script that works perfectly on linux:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import random

script, dirnum = sys.argv

#Create list of filenames
filenames = glob.glob('./*%s/*%s*.txt' % (dirnum, dirnum))

#Open Random file from list
select_file = open(random.choice(filenames))
file_content = selct_file.read()
print(file_content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `os.path.join` to create a platform agnostic file path to use with `glob`:

```
search_path = os.path.join('*%s*' % dirnum, '*%s*.txt' % dirnum)
filenames = glob.glob(search_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the reply of @daveruinseverything, you can alternatively use the `pathlib.Path` and the f-strings:

```py
from pathlib import Path
search_path = Path('./')/ f'*{dirnum}' / f'*{dirnum}*.txt'
filenames = glob.glob(str(search_path))
```

This works equally well for recursive search using `/**/`.